# Shared property file among instances in JBoss 6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss6.x

I've encoutered this issue. We have several instances of Java EE apps deployed on JBoss 6.1 and I would like to have shared property file among those instances.

When I put this file under `conf` folder in my current running instance I am able to load it via 
`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(FILE).openStream()` but I wasn't able to make it run from different folders(I tried all, minimal and standard). I suppose that there is a simple solution for this but I don't see it.

Thanks for any suggestions.

P.S. I understand that I could do similar thing with `JNDI` or environmental variable, but I really would like to use this approach. Also file is supposed to be only read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try assigning an alias to conf dir ,  and then in rest of instances you can load it via `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(FILE).openStream()`   where in FILE is referred via alias

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but issue is already solved, my boss just told me that we don't really require this functionality and having the file separated in each instance is good enough:-)